# In C#, is there an "easy" way to perform string.Join on complex type list?

Tags: c#, string

Let's say I have this object:

```
public class Role {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAssigned { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

A member can have multiple roles: `member.Roles = List<Role>();`

If I wanted to join the member's roles into a comma separated list of the role names, is there an easy way (similar to `string.Join(",", member.Roles);` - which doesn't work because a role is a complex type)?

Comment: Maybe using something like `member.Roles.Select<Role, string>(x => x.Name).ToList<string>()`?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
using System.Linq

string.Join(",", member.Roles.Select(r => r.Name))
```

Comment: rock on, thanks for the really quick answer (and Colonel Panic for the using statement!)

Answer (score 11):

If you only want the Name property, then other answers are good

But if you have more properties, adjust your `ToString()` to match:

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Name: {0}. Slug : {1}", Name, Slug);
}
```

etc. and then call it as

```
 String.Join(", ", member.Roles);
```

You wouldn't need to call

```
String.Join(", ", member.Roles.Select(x => x.ToString())
```

as it would be called internally by object inside `String.Join()`, so if you override `ToString()`, you just call

```
String.Join(", ", member.Roles);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the overload of [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.100%29)(new in .NET 4) which takes an `IEnumerable<String>` and a little bit of Linq:

```
String joined = string.Join(",", member.Roles.Select(r => r.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

One other option is to override the `ToString()` method of the `Role` class to return what you want and then just issue this statement.

```
var joined = string.Join(",", member.Roles)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple properties to be selected in the comma separated values:

```
var csvdata = member.Roles.Select(x => string.Join(",", new string[] { x.Name, x.Slug , x.DateAssigned}));
```

I had this requirement to select multiple properties to csv.
May be this might help someone.